# What to do when passion for Work exceeds passion for Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith

If I want to rephrase the words, it would sound like, What is the guideline for the people who are addicted to work but not for ibadat? In academic words, I am in [flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzPky5Xe1-s) with my work but not with my ibadat.

I am attaching a graph for the flow chart from the refereed video to make it clear.

[image: Skill-Challenge Graph]

I mean I am in the comfort zone when I am engaged in a worldly thing (specially my work, which I love). But not so when I am doing something regarding Islam (I can't say I love to pray, or do ibadat).

In Summery:

- I love work but not Ibadat
- I am comfortable with work but not Ibadat
- I am addicted to work but not Ibadat

So, what is the solution to this? To what extend I can keep doing it? How to shift from work to Ibadat?

Please give solution with Quran and Sahih Hadith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put my answer in short ideas and try to think about them I will not go into details becaus I'm sure you know the answers.

What is the reason of creation is it to work or to worship Allah?

Work is a mean of gaining to live your test period on this Earth, stay focus , remember what is the aim and what are the means, do not switch the mean into an  objective

How bad you like to win? and how much you hate to fail?

What are your thoughts about failing on the final day?

People like to do things they enjoy.

Ibadat needs hard work before you reach to the point of enjoying them.

To start enjoying ibadat you need to go back to basics, undertand the meaning and objective of each one.

A very important point, "Know ALLAH", learn what are his names, and their meanings, if you know him well you will have your life changed because you will realise details you do not notice now.

Fix your Niyah so you dedicate your hard work to Allah, by  benifiting people and Islam  with your work (do not work for your self or company, work for Allah).